# How to use wait.for and MSSQL on Node.js

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I want to port some data from MSSQL server to a MongoDB using node.js on Ubuntu.

I want to extract data  with [npm-mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssq) with [npm-wait.for](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wait.for) than its just an easy insert to Mongo.

I have to make a query and for each of the results I have to make an other query to assemble the data from MSSQL. I built it half way with callbacks but its not so pretty, that's I want to use wait for.

Can someone help me how to do MSSQL queries with `waitfor` in JavaScript?

Comment: Your question is too broad. I recommend you to try to code a solution, and the ask for help with specific code examples.

Comment: yeah, I'm doing it without wait.for, learned more about using callbacks, so now I can control whats happening and when.
Should I delete this question?

Comment: Yes, best to delete this question